# Distance between anchors

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I set 2 anchors. The distance calculated between the 2 anchors is pretty much accurate.
Translating those anchors pose to screen points (worldToScreenPoint), the distance calculated using the 2D (x,y) points  greater by 8 cm.

Am I missing something?

```
  Vector3  vecCoord;
  Pose     pose;

  for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < nItems; nIndex++)
  {
   pose = listAnchors.get(nIndex).getPose();

   m_vecPose.x = pose.tx();
   m_vecPose.y = pose.ty();
   m_vecPose.z = pose.tz();

   vecCoord = camera.worldToScreenPoint(m_vecArcorePose);
  }
```

listAnchors contains captured anchors.
Calculating distance between 2 poses (e.g. `listAnchors.get(nIndex).getPose()` and `listAnchors.get(nIndex+1).getPose()`) comes out accurate.
Calculating the distance between those anchors screen points (received in vecCoord) is not accurate.